# In which case should a wavelet transform be applied instead of a Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, wavelets

I was wondering what are the advantages (and possibly the drawbacks) of using a wavelet transform instead of a Fourier transform for the signal processing, are there simple examples to illustrate that ?

Is the convolution product also simplified in the wavelet domain ?

Comment: Read also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279980/difference-between-fourier-transform-and-wavelets?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

There are several good reasons for using wavelets over Fourier.  To name a few:

1. The Fourier basis is *nonlocal*, meaning that signal features such as transients, discontinuities, and edges (in the case of images) show up in *all* the Fourier coefficients.  This is because the functions $e^{ikt}$ are nonzero for all $t$.  Consequentially, this means that with Fourier we can know that there is such a feature but we don't know where it is in the signal.  Wavelets, on the other hand, can provide *localized* information in the sense that we can identify both the frequencies and locations of signal features.  If you're working with images, discontinuous signals, or signals with multiple regions/scales of behavior, this is perhaps the best reason to use wavelets.
2. Compression and sparsity.  Briefly, wavelets can represent the key features of a signal very efficiently.  This is the reason wavelet expansions have become extremely popular in data compression and compressed sensing applications.  I am biased (I study compressed sensing), but I would say the most important setting for wavelets is in *signal recovery* i.e. reconstructing a signal from measurements of it.

There are several things that become more difficult with wavelets, however:

1. Convolution products are not necessarily simple in the wavelet domain.  The reason convolutions are simple in the Fourier basis is that the functions $e^{ikt}$ are the eigenfunctions for translation invariant operators; wavelet basis function $\psi_{j,k}$ do not enjoy this property.  That being said, there are operators called *Calderon-Zygmund* operators which do (nearly) diagonalize in Wavelet bases.
2. Much of the language of signal processing is still adapting to the wavelet framework: things like bandwidth, resolution, frequency and so forth are based on a Fourier interpretation of a signal.  Wavelet bases, to a certain extent, can supersede some of these ideas and it can be difficult to draw the necessary connections to classical signal processing.  For instance, *sparse* functions are the appropriate version of 'band-limited' functions in a wavelet setting.
3. The mathematics involved is much more difficult than with Fourier (if you really want to understand what you're using and not just swing a hammer).

I would recommend picking up a book on Wavelets and looking at the examples - Mallat's *A Wavelet Tour of Signal Processing* is not a bad place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to achive with it.
If you have a (quasi-)periodic signal and want to estimate the used frequencies you use the fourier-transform. If you just want to interpolate between two sample point use wavelets. These are only examples.

The convolution product is not simplified in the wavelet domain, use FFT

Comment: For clarification: a mathmatics student once asked me why I didn't use wavelets for connecting my measurements instead of fitting it to a normal distribution. This way the graph would go through every point exactly, the fit would still have residuals. But that wasn't the point of my task, I had to estimate the expectation and standard deviation. It depends on the task